# Store NSTreeNode as CKRecordValueStore to cloudkit

Tags: objective-c, macos, icloud, cloudkit

Is there any way to store NSTreeNode as CKRecordValueStore to cloudkit.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. CKRecordValue only supports a few predefined types and no custom types (see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecordvalue?language=objc ).

You have to find a way to map your tree structure onto a bunch of these types, and write your own serialization/deserialization logic.

The ultimate CKRecordValue type is NSData, which means that you store your tree as a binary BLOB with any structure you want.

It depends on the task which structure is the best. For example, if you already know how to convert your tree to JSON, it might be easiest to upload it as NSString or NSData.